# Migrate Team Project from TFS 2013 To TFS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, migration, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

I need to migrate one Team Project from TFS 2013 update 4 server to instance of TFS 2015. The source project is located in default collection. The default collection contains many team projects and I can not migrate them because there is security reasons. There is no possibility to get whole team collection database. The splitting of collection is also not possible because the database and TFS application server manages another company. I can use only TFS API.

I found TFS Integration Tools but I'm not able to install it. There are two errors while i'm installing it:

- Unsupported API (integration tools requires team explorer 2008, 2010 or Dev11)
- Probably Unsupported version of DB

Is there any other approach how to migrate specified team project to another instance TFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If splitting the team project collection is unachievable, you need to use TFS Integration tool. And to fix the error message you got above (integration tools requires team explorer 2008, 2010 or Dev11), please first try installing Team Explorer 2012 then install again. Also have a check on this blog for the details on how to handle it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2012/07/04/tfs-integration-tools-issue-this-tool-requires-the-tfs-client-object-model.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using the GIT-TF client. Similar to the approuch highlighted here:  http://www.teamfoundation.co.za/2014/10/move-from-git-to-tfs-version-control/ 
but you will start from a TFS repo to a new TFS repo.

Both options are going to be lossy (some of the metadata will go lost), it is a lot easier to split out the collection.

Comment: TFS is a lot more than just source control. Remember the work items. Build setup will likely have to be re-worked regardless.

You can easily just do an xcopy of the files from one location on your disk to another and checkin the new location. That will get you your files without the history. Much like GIT-TF I suppose. 

Your best bet is to use the TFS integration tools with all the quirks involced - a fantastic readup is http://blogs.ripple-rock.com/richarderwin/2016/01/27/InstallingTheTFSIntegrationToolsToMigratesyncBetweenTFS2015AndVSTS.aspx